# Derivation of energy function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization

Given the following energy function $E(d)$ (also found [here](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/sq_rome_g2/paper_camready.pdf) on page 3):
$$
E_d = \sum_{x,y \in \Omega} \left(d_{x,y} - \hat{d}_{x,y}\right)^2 +
      \lambda \sum_{x,y} \left(
                w_x(x,y)\left(
                   \frac{\partial^2 d_{x,y}}{\partial x^2}
                \right)^2 + 
                w_y(x,y)\left(
                   \frac{\partial^2 d_{x,y}}{\partial y^2}
                \right)^2
              \right)             
$$
How would one calculate $ \frac{\partial E}{\partial d}$ ?

$ \hat{d},  \lambda ,w_x,w_y $ are known parameters.

I started to rewrite this equation in a matrix form but I still couldn't get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just as {$x,\dot x,\ddot x$} are all independent variables, the variable $d$ is independent of the various derivatives of $d$ with respect to {$x,y$}.

In matrix form, your question reduces to the following (wherein $A\!:\!B$ represents the Frobenius product) 
$$\eqalign{
  E_d &= (D-\hat D):(D-\hat D) + \lambda K\cr\cr
  dE_d &= 2\,(D-\hat D):dD  + 0\cr\cr
  \frac{\partial E_d}{\partial D} &= 2\,(D-\hat D) \cr\cr
}$$

Have we abused the letter D enough in this problem?